# Retrofit2, how I can convert response with diferent object names but same data types

Tags: java, android, kotlin, serialization, retrofit2

I have one call that return different objects name, in this case, each name is the hash of your wallet address,  but I would like to treat them indifferently because all that matters is the data that is inside them, using a standard converter like Gson I am not able to do this, is there any way to do it manually?

```
{
"0x1234": {
    "success": true,
    "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
    "total": 500
},
"0x1244445": {
    "success": true,
    "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
    "total": 324
},
"0x47851":{
    "success": true,
    "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
    "total": 324
}
}
```

My Repository:

```
class WalletsResumeRepository(
private val service: apiService
) {
suspend fun getAddressData(listAddress: List<String>): Flow<Result<List<DetailModel>>> =
    flow {
        emit(Result.success(service.getWalletResume(listAddress))
    }.catch { e ->
        emit(Result.failure(RuntimeException("Something went wrong ${e.cause}")))
    }
   }
```

my repository always falls into the catch scenario with an NPE, remembering that the response can have countless addresses so infinite object names, how can I treat them as generics and map only the responses as lists? or something like that?

Service.kt

```
suspend fun getWalletResume(@Path("address") wallet: String): WalletDetailDTO
```

WalletDTO

```
data class WalletDetailDTO(
    val success: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("cache_last_updated")
    val cacheLastUpdated: Long?,
    val totalSlp: Int?
)
```

Comment: What is the signature of the service call `apiService.getWalletResume` ?

Comment: Can you influence the API design? Using values as keys makes your life miserable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your question, this is less to do with retrofit and more with JSON parsing.
Because the payload structure is a bit awkward I suggest you consume it in two steps:

- step 1. Consume the `content` `success`, `cache_last_updated` and `total`
- step 2. Add the `id`

```kotlin
data class DetailModel(val id: String = "", val success: Boolean, val cache_last_updated: Long, val total: Int) 

interface apiService {
    @GET("....")
    fun getWalletResume( listAddress: List<String> ): Call<Map<String, DetailModel>>
}
```

The result of calling `apiService.getWalletResume` is `Map<String, DetailModel>` which you then process in step 2.

**Example**

```kotlin
val json = """
    {
      "0x1234": {
        "success": true,
        "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
        "total": 500
      },
      "0x1244445": {
        "success": true,
        "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
        "total": 324
      },
      "0x47851": {
        "success": true,
        "cache_last_updated": 1642815869695,
        "total": 324
      }
    }
""".trimIndent()


data class DetailModel(val id: String = "", val success: Boolean, val cache_last_updated: Long, val total: Int)

fun main() {
    val gson = Gson()
    val type: Type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, DetailModel>?>() {}.type
    
    // step 1. simulates the retrofit call
    val mapResult: Map<String, DetailModel> = gson.fromJson(json, type)

    // step 2
    val result = mapResult.map { entry -> entry.value.copy(id = entry.key) }

    println(result) 
    // [DetailModel(id=0x1234, success=true, cache_last_updated=1642815869695, total=500), DetailModel(id=0x1244445, success=true, cache_last_updated=1642815869695, total=324), DetailModel(id=0x47851, success=true, cache_last_updated=1642815869695, total=324)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are just looking for a response type of `Map<String, WalletDetailDTO>`. Then you can simply look at the "values" in the map to get a unique list of objects.

Then your service call looks like

```kotlin
@GET("....")
suspend fun getWalletDetails(...): Map<String, WalletDetailDTO>
```

Then when you consume that data you'd pull out the values:

```kotlin
val mapOfWalletDetails = apiService.getWalletResume(...)

val walletDetailCollection: Collection<WalletDetailDTO> = mapOfWalletDetails.values()
```

This final `walletDetailCollection` seems to be what you are looking for if you just want to ignore the keys in the original map.